# Remove "pubdate" attribute from Submitted Time tag in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

Currently when a node or comment is submitted it gets a Submitted text saying "Submitted by user on Wed, 04/01/2015 - 18:07"

The mark-up for this is:

```
<span>Submitted by *user* on <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="2015-04-01T18:07:34+0000">Wed, 04/01/2015 - 18:07</time></span>
```

What I need to do is remove the "pubdate" attribute from the tag because the it is failing on W3C validation.

I have tried to add the following code in my template.php file but had no luck

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $attributes['datetime'] = '<time'.drupal_attributes($attributes) .'>'.$variables['date'] . '</time>';
}
```

How can I remove the "pubdate" attribute in the Submitted by tag?

Comment: In your `ThemeName_preprocess_node` you need to set some value into `$variables` otherwise no changes will make it to your template. It's most likely theme dependent what variable you need to set, but you possibly want to override the current value of `$variables['date']`. Can you post the relevant part of your theme's node.tpl.php?

Comment: Hi dblue, thanks for the reply. The node.tpl.php for the submitted line is:                                   <?php print $submitted; ?>            and then this prints the following in html:                                 <span>Submitted by *user* on <time pubdate="pubdate" datetime="2015-04-01T18:07:34+0000">Wed, 04/01/2015 - 18:07</time></span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `$variables['submitted'] is the one you want to override in your theme's preprocess_node function. Try this as a starting point:

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username', array('!username' => $variables['name']));
}
```

Which will replace the $submitted variable with "Submitted by username" (where the username will be linked to the user's profile page).

Comment: The $variable was "$variable['pubdate']", so what I did was theme that in my template.php like this:

$variables['pubdate'] = '<time datetime="' . format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'c') . '">' . $variables['date'] . '</time>';

And it worked. Thanks for your help dblue. Pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Need to hook into "preprocess_node" to access the $submitted variable like so:

```
function THEME-NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

$variables['pubdate'] = '<time datetime="' . format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'c') . '">' . $variables['date'] . '</time>';

$variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' =>$variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['pubdate']));
}
```